# JavaScript condition not being met

Tags: javascript

I have created the below code for a subscribe form and for the most part it is working fine apart from, however the following condition does not seem to be working:

```
if (subFieldUpdated === true && subValidEmail === true) {
      $("#modEmailSub, #modFNameSub, #modLNameSub").val("");
    }
```

What is happening is that when the subValidEmail is entered correctly it clears all of the other entered data which leads me to believe that the subFieldUpdated === true condition is not being picked up correctly?

What I am looking for is that the form will only clear the values once all fields have been entered & a valid email is present.

Any suggestions/advice would be great as I have tried a few things now but with no luck.

```
$("#modSubCard").submit(function() {

var modSubField = ["#modEmailSub", "#modFNameSub", "#modLNameSub"];

$("#modEmailSub, #modFNameSub, #modLNameSub").removeClass("border-red");

contactValid(modSubField);

function contactValid(field) {
  var subFieldUpdated = true;
  var subValidEmail = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    if ($(field[i]).val() == "") {
      $(field[i]).addClass("border-red");
      subFieldUpdated[i] = false;
    }
    if (!validateEmail($("#modEmailSub").val())) {
      $("#modEmailSub").addClass("border-red");
      subValidEmail = false;
    }
    if (subFieldUpdated === true && subValidEmail === true) {
      $("#modEmailSub, #modFNameSub, #modLNameSub").val("");
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: replace `subFieldUpdated[i] = false;` with `subFieldUpdated = false;` Because `Array === boolean` always return a false value.

Comment: already tried this, makes no difference

Comment: Have you tried debugging the field and checking what subFieldUpdated actually does  throughout your function? We don't see all of your code here for all we know your field.length is not filled correctly and is 0 so the for loop might not even be running to set your subFieldUpdated  to false.

Comment: Yes tried to debug but with no luck as no errors showing in the log.  The loop is certainly running as it is picking up the relevant ID's in the 'mobSubField' array and applying the 'border-red' class when necessary.  The problem seems to be relevant to the 'subFieldUpdated' boolean condition - however, there is no error when running the script and no clear reason as to why it is not working.  Headache is in full flow!

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code. It will works for you.

```
var modSubField = ["#modEmailSub", "#modFNameSub", "#modLNameSub"];

$("#modEmailSub, #modFNameSub, #modLNameSub").removeClass("border-red");

contactValid(modSubField);

function contactValid(field) {
  var subFieldUpdated = 0;
  var subValidEmail = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    if ($(field[i]).val() == "") {
      $(field[i]).addClass("border-red");
      subFieldUpdated = subFieldUpdated + 1;
    }
    if (!validateEmail($("#modEmailSub").val())) {
      $("#modEmailSub").addClass("border-red");
      subValidEmail = false;
    }
    if (subFieldUpdated === 0 && subValidEmail === true) {
      $("#modEmailSub, #modFNameSub, #modLNameSub").val("");
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: This does not work as now it will not clear the form when everything is entered correctly